# How can I help Intellisense find include paths based on CMake variables?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, android-ndk, intellisense

I'm trying to use Android NDK in my project, for which I'm using Visual Studio Code. This means I have a CMakeLists.txt file that uses a ANDROID_NDK variable in order to find both include and source files, and building works. However, Intellisense is not working, meaning that coding is a real pain since it can't recognize includes. I tried using CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS but it just won't work as intended. Should I just manually edit vscode's includePath and expect everyone I share my code with to do the same? Whatever the solution may be, I'd rather have CMakeLists.txt modified so it can help any IDE/editor, but vscode-specific solutions are ok if there's no other way.

I tried set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON) and editing the appropriate vscode variable for compile commands path but it just won't help.

Comment: Have you tried using the cmake plugin?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes of course, but the plugin only helps when it knows include paths beforehand. CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK is derived much later according to these rules https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#id23

Comment: fairly sure that after doing a build the plugin will setup intellisense to use whatever settings were used for the build